# определить корневую дерикторию

Tags: php

У меня возникла проблема в определение корневой директории сайта. В чём проблема собственно, я могу установить сайт в корень доменна, но не могу его поставить допустим в отдельную папку типа: site.ru/cms/
Для простоты, [вот мой гит сразу](https://github.com/kepchuk08/web-bhop-stats)
В файле application/core/Router.php я пытался сделать так:

```php
public function match() {
     define('URL_DIR', '/'.trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));
     $arr = explode(URL_DIR, $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
     $url = $arr[1];

     foreach ($this->routes as $route => $params) {
          if (preg_match($route, $url, $matches)) {
               foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
                    if (is_string($key)) {
                         if (is_numeric($match)) {
                              $match = (int) $match;
                         }
                         $params[$key] = $match;
                    }
               }
               $this->params = $params;
               return true;
          }
     }
     return false;
}
```

У меня открывается главная страница, но остальные страницы не работают, плюс в стилях пока не укажешь эту доп. папку они так же не работают, по этому прицепил еще константу URL_DIR, чтобы после можно было правильно указать путь до картинки css, js и тому прочее.

Comment: а вопрос в чём?

Comment: неправильное значение в константе URL_DIR, определяй от корня диска,а не url

Comment: Попытался написать define('URL_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));, результата не доло, страница вообще перестала открывать

Comment: начать, наверное, следует из того, чтобы вынести данную настройку в конфиг. убирать из ссылки при разборке маршрута, добавлять при построении ссылки, учитывать при генерации ссылок на стили/скрипты.